# ASP.NET dropdown list to erase duplicates and blanks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am programing in C# and ASP.NET. I have created a drop-down list from a procedure to filter my data; however, the dropdown list contains duplicates and blanks that I would like to get rid of.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
protected void BtnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Filter = DDlModel.SelectedValue.ToString();
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spSearchLaptopInventory_Model", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", Filter);

    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sd.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    Label1.Text = "Record has been filtered";
}
```

I am expecting for the blanks and duplicates to be erased out the drop down when I load the page.

Comment: What does your stored procedure look like? Would be best if that would take care of filtering out blanks, and remove duplicates ....And can you please also show us the table structure from where you fetch that data, and provide some sample data?

Comment: @marc_s is correct. You need to solve this in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Distinct method in a procedure or in C#

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).